# sprintf write to string with \n

Tags: c, linux, printf

I have this code:

```
str1= "a";
str2= "b";
sprintf(string, "0 %s %s\n", str1, str2);
```

string then contains:

```
"0 a b"
```

instead of (what I want):

```
"0 a b
"
```

How can I solve that?

Note: I place the quoting of the var string inside " so that you could understand the situation.

Edit:

#### **Problem solved** I added 1 to the size and it worked. I don't completely understand why but it's solved

Comment: How do you know that string is incorrect? Try to printf it or see all its characters in debugger.

Comment: Your `string` will end up with a newline at the end of it (how do you discover it does not ?). Make sure `string` is big enough to hold the result.

Comment: strsize = (2 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 2 + 1) * sizeof(char);

Comment: Post a complete example demonstrating the problem.  The code you show is correct.

Comment: If you posted the entire example, we could tell you why.

Comment: Regarding your understanding, you have to remember that strings are terminated by an extra character, the so called *null* characters `'\0'`. If there's not enough space for it then that will be written out of bounds and you will have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Answer (score 2):

If you are on a Windows computer you might need `\r\n` instead of just the newline. The library should handle it though.

Comment: it's in linux, though. (I'll add it to the tags)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like its working for me. I put brackets `[]` around the string to prove it.

Have a look here: http://ideone.com/3rbwF

Answer (score 1):

Allocate enough space for `string`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

main() {
    char string[7];
    char str1[] = "a";
    char str2[] = "b";
    sprintf(string, "0 %s %s\n", str1, str2);
    printf("%s", string);
}
```

Comment: In that case, it would be: char string[8]; and not what you show. In what you show the space for \0 is not alloced

Comment: @brunoais yes it is. "0 a b\n" takes up 7 chars. (the newline is escaped in the source code, in the compiled code it takes up just 1 char)

Comment: Ups, I miscounted the number of chars. he's right.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is `sprintf(string, "0 %s %s\n\n", str1, str2);`

In your example the string actually contains "0 a b\n" which means that anything printed after the `\n` will appear on the next line. If you want a blank line below it, you need another line break.

Comment: Doesn't work. The \n is not inside the string. And I used printf to test it.